# Using J, is there any way to draw an isigraph within a tab?

Tags: j

I'm trying to draw an isigraph within a tab.

So far I have the following code (that I modified from the gl2 and tabs demos):

```
NB. =========================================================
Tabdemo=: 0 : 0
pc tabdemo closeok escclose;
cc prefs tab closable movable;

tabnew View;
minwh 450 350;
cc gs isigraph flush;
bin s1;

tabnew Editor;
cc gross radiobutton;
cc paid checkbox;
bin z s1 z;

tabend;
)

NB. =========================================================
tabdemo_run=: 3 : 0
require 'gl2'
coinsert 'jgl2'
wd Tabdemo
wd 'set prefs active 0'
wd 'set prefs tooltip 0 "toolip view"'
wd 'set prefs tooltip 1 "toolip editor"'
wd 'set prefs icon 0 qstyle::sp_fileicon'
wd 'set prefs icon 1 qstyle::sp_diropenicon'
wd 'pmove 400 10 400 200'
wd 'pshow'
)

NB. =========================================================
demo_gs_paint=: 3 : 0
'w h'=: glqwh''
NB. draw grid
glfill 255 255 255 255
glrgb 128 128 18
glpen 0 1
for_i. 50* i.>.h%50 do.
  gllines 0,i,w,i
end.
for_i. 50* i.>.w%50 do.
  gllines i,0,i,h
end.
)

NB. =========================================================
tabdemo_prefs_tabclose=: 3 : 0
wd 'set prefs tabclose ',prefs_select
)

NB. =========================================================
tabdemo_close=: 3 : 0
wd 'pclose'
showevents_jqtide_ 0
)

showevents_jqtide_ 2
tabdemo_run''
```

When I run the script, I'm expecting to see a graph of a grid show up under the "View" tab.

However, I'm unfortunately get a blank screen on the View tab. Is there anything I'm doing wrong, or is there simply no way to draw an isigraph within a tab?

I'm at my wit's end trying to make this work. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: It's been a while since I have done this, but I don't see how you have actually invoked `demo_gs_paint` to run. Perhaps `tabdemo_gs_paint` is what you want because you have declared the parent as `tabdemo` and `gs` as the child. Just a hint, as I don't think I have the familiarity to provide a true answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: That was actually the solution! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help. I will write up a quick answer so that it is not flagged as having no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pc tabdemo closeok escclose;` creates the parent object and `cc gs isagraph flush;` creates a child of that parent and runs paint to populate the tab. Unfortunately, you have only created the verb `demo_gs_paint` and that is not the name of the object that you want to paint.

The form for specifying objects is `parent_child_verb` and the parent is `tabdemo`, so the correct answer is to create the verb `tabdemo_gs_paint` and it will be invoked appropriately. The comments in response to your question above verify that this works.